# I am relatively everywhere

Tags: riddle, word

Have fun with this riddle:

> I am everywhere but I am relative.
> That means, I am slower when I move fast.
> I am also faster if something interesting happens.
> I was born with an explosion, with a human or with an operating system, depending on what is important to you. 
> I am unidirectional but I am split into multiple sections.
> I can exist without you but you need me to exist.

Who am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You're time.

> I am everywhere

> Time exists everywhere.

> I am relative.
> That means, I am slower when I move fast.

> Time slows down when people move fast (general relativity).

> I am also faster if something interesting happens.

> Time flies when you're having fun.

> I was born with an explosion, with a human or with an operating system, depending on what is important to you.

> How we count is anno mundi, anno domini, or from the UNIX epoch.

> I am unidirectional but I am split into multiple sections.

> Time goes in one direction but is divided into years, etc.

> I can exist without you but you need me to exist.

> It can certainly exist without people, but I'm not sure about the second half of this.